# Click event not recognized on higher z-index element

Tags: javascript, events, click, z-index

I have a code snippet like this : (notice frame_bookmark has z-index 100)

```
<div id="select_bar">
  <div class="frame_bookmark" style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:695px;z-index:100;width:15px;height:15px;background:#df3367;border-radius:10px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

The alert box is shown when I have JavaScript like

```
$("#select_bar").click(function()
{
  alert('down');
});
```

But not shown when I have JavaScript like:

```
$(".frame_bookmark").click(function()
{
  alert('down');
});
```

Comment: please, be more accurate in code formatting

Comment: there's nothing in this provided code to prove that the z-index is higher.  You should not use z-index without understanding the stacking context.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you posted is exactly your code, your missing a closing `</div>` which will definitely mess you up. It should be:

```
<div id="select_bar">
    <div class="frame_bookmark" style="position:absolute;top:1px;left:695px;z-index:100;width:15px;height:15px;background:#df3367;border-radius:10px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/
your code is pretty working )

Answer (score 0):

form my understanding when you call a ID in jquery just like JavaScript it defaults at eq(0).

but when using the attributes class / name you want to specify your indexed numeric for

example

**$(".frame_bookmark:eq(0)")  / $(".frame_bookmark").eq(0)**

and or use the .each function